# propagating state even when backlogged

Tags: okhttp

In Brave (zipkin tracer), we attach state read by interceptors by controlling the Dispatcher's ExecutorService.

It works like this..

- attach a span to a thread local
- wrap an executor service which re-attaches the calling thread's span to a runnable
- make the dispatcher use that executor service

This works for synchronous requests (since they don't use the dispatcher thread anyway) and normal asynchronous requests.

It doesn't work when there are more in-flight connections than permitted, because asynchronous requests are pushed into a ready queue before they are executed. The ready queue is not processed by the calling thread of the request, so the re-attach won't work. When an interceptor runs on a delayed request, it cannot see its calling span which breaks tracing.

I was thinking that maybe the application interceptor might not have this problem. If the host/connection limit was enforced (via the mentioned queue) at the network level, I would be able to coordinate the state by dual-registering an interceptor. This interceptor could re-attach the state without relying on thread locals by mapping application/network level requests.

Sadly, this doesn't work because the host/connection limit is enforced (via the mentioned queue) at the application level, so I'm stumped.

I would like to be able to trace requests especially when they are backlogged. Any ideas?

Hats off to brianm for finding this problem, btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an internal OkHttpClient wrapper implementing Call.Factory which adds an initial interceptor:

```
public class HttpClient implements Call.Factory {

private final OkHttpClient ok;

HttpClient(final OkHttpClient ok) {
    this.ok = ok;
}

/**
 * Implements Call.Factory, uses implicit (thread local) Ctx
 */
public Call newCall(final Request request) {
    return newCall(Ctx.fromThread().orElseGet(Ctx::empty), request);
}


public Call newCall(Ctx ctx, final Request request) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder b = this.ok.newBuilder();
    b.interceptors().add(0, new CtxInterceptor(ctx));
    return b.build().newCall(request);
}
```

to solve this problem. It is not transparent, however, so may not be good for Brave. It works fine, because in practice once a client is configured, you only really use the `Call.Factory` interface :-)

The `Ctx` bit is just the context with stuff we want to propagate, we can do it implicit or explicit, hence the extra method to explicitly take it.